# pyomo - difficulties including a power into a constraint expression

Tags: python, constraints, formula, pyomo, exponent

I am trying to model a thermodynamic relationship, which happens to have terms x**1.25. However, when including the fomrmula I receive an error message.
Here is the constraint expression:

```
FOR p_m in LIST1
model.cons.add(sum(model.mix1[b_n,p_m]*quals[b_n]['q_qual1']**1.25 for b_n in BLEND) \
                   - model.prods[p_m]*fin[p_m]['q_qual1_min']**1.25 >=0)
```

and here is the error:

```
File "ext_mod_v0k.py", line 154, in <module>
    - model.prods[p_m]*fin[p_m]['q_qual1_min']**1.25 >=0)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\expr\numvalue.py", line 784, in __mul__
    return _generate_mul_expression(_mul,self,other)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\expr\numeric_expr.py", line 1780, in _generate_mul_expression
    if not (_other.__class__ in native_types or _other.is_expression_type()):
AttributeError: 'complex' object has no attribute 'is_expression_type'
```

When I replace the "1.25" with a "1" or a "2" the code runs through smoothly. I have also tried pow(), but the same result. What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try casting your power base to float first: `float(x)**1.25`

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I  wrapped the expression into a float-statement. however the error message came back. File "ext_mod_v0k.py", line 154, in <module>
    - model.prods[p_m]*float(fin[p_m]['q_qual1_min'])**1.25 >=0)  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\expr\numvalue.py", line 784, in __mul__
    return _generate_mul_expression(_mul,self,other)...
AttributeError: 'complex' object has no attribute 'is_expression_type'.... any other idea?

Comment: thanks for the edits dpapadopoulos. i am still pretty new to this.

Comment: Huh. Are you expecting the quantity to be a complex number? That's not something Pyomo has support for right now, because the optimization solvers generally do not support complex numbers.

Comment: not a complex number. its just that this particular thermodynamic property in a mixture has an impact that is reflected by the **1.25. And as said, I can run the constraint with a **2 without any problems, but why not with 1.25? I have seen a similar equation **1.25 in another programme that I found on a lecturer's website. I can run that programme without issues. So still puzzled why it does not work in my context. ??

Comment: Oh, maybe your quantity is becoming negative in the base? In that case, the **1.25 would cause the quantity to become imaginary.

Comment: you are a star. indeed, i had a small negative -1E-06 as default value for my variables to avoid having "NaN" . now turned this to 1E-06 and it all goes through smoothly. thanks a lot. :-)